# How do you build a gadget + mobile app that work together through bluetooth?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, bluetooth

The company I work at is looking to create a gadget. Something like rollerskates. We want to build a mobile app that comes with it where you can use to see your location and where you've travelled.

How does something like this work? Is there a bluetooth chip that we need to buy and insert into the machine? Is there anything like this? I see companies like Rocketskate (https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/petertreadway/acton-r-rocketskates-worlds-first-smart-wearable-m) doing this.

Any help would be really appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a Low energy BT eval board from Nordic Semiconductor.  If you buy the eval board,  you can use one of their template apps for iOS or Android to send the data to the mobile device.

If you are going to get fancy, you'll need to write some code for the BT radio node embedded processor side , send the data over the BT profile to the phone, and display/process it.

They have everything you need in one place and it's the easiest to get started.

Good luck.